# SSMS 2008 R2 - Create Table Dialog

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2008

I just recently upgraded to SSMS 2008 R2, and I'm working with a few Azure databases in our development environment.

I was surprised to see that, when I right click on the **Tables** folder and click **New Table**, a new query window is opened with a predefined `CREATE TABLE` script template, rather then the more UI friendly "design view" that I'm used to seeing.

**My question :**

Is there any way to enable the design view for creating tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx) for Visual Studio 2010 - 2012.

Unlike SSMS 2008 R2; this still allows you to access the Design view for a Windows Azure SQL Database.

[As indicated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx) you don't need to have Visual Studio installed initially to use the tools; it will install the Visual Studio Shell for you.

To do so:

1. Install SSDT
2. Open Visual Studio
3. On the left you should have a tab called "SQL Server Object Explorer" (If it isn't there, you can find it under the View menu on the top bar)
4. Within the tab; right click on SQL Server and click "Add SQL Server"
5. Enter you SQL Azure connection details
6. Once the connection has loaded; open the Tables folder inside the database
7. Right click the desired table and click "View Designer"

[image: SSDT Table Designer]

Comment: Man, I had no idea something like this even existed. Thanks for the suggestion!